# Match expression vs pattern matching function

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm trying to convert the following pattern matching function to a match expression:

```
let reverse ls =
    let rec rev acc =
        function
        | h :: t -> rev (h :: acc) t
        | [] -> acc

    rev [] ls
```

When I attempt to convert to equivalent match expression type mismatch errors occur:

```
let reverse ls =
    let rec rev acc =
        match acc with
        | h :: t -> rev (h :: acc) t
        | [] -> acc

    rev [] ls
```

The desired output for both is:

```
reverse [ 1; 2; 3 ]
// val it : int list = [3; 2; 1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your match expression is not equivalent. To get the equivalent of your `function`-based code, the function should look like this:

```
let rec rev acc x =
    match x with
    | h :: t -> rev (h :: acc) t
    | [] -> acc
```

Note the extra parameter `x` - that's the difference. The `function` keyword is equivalent not to just `match`, but to a *function* that matches on its parameter. In other words, `function ...` is equivalent to `fun x -> match x with ...`